# Laravel Sqlite database cannot be connected to

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, sqlite

When I navigate to my app on my server (Ubuntu) i get the following:

```
Data: { message: 'could not find driver (SQL: select * from "projects" order by "created_at" desc)',
  exception: 'Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException',
  file: '/root/project/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php',
  line: 664,
  trace:
   [ { file: '/root/project/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php',
       line: 624,
       function: 'runQueryCallback',
       class: 'Illuminate\\Database\\Connection',
       type: '->' },
```

However locally it works. So i thought perhaps the driver is not install, but when I run the following it shows the I have sqlite installed:

```
 sqlite3 -version
3.19.3 2017-06-08 14:26:16 0ee482a1e0eae22e08edc8978c9733a96603d4509645f348ebf55b579e89636b
```

My database config looks like this with the default being sqlite:

```
'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.db')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

Whats my next step to figure out why this wont work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sqlite3 installed, but not php's driver for it. The driver is also called sqlite3, so for e.g. Ubuntu/Debian that would be `sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite3`.

Comment: yes perfect thanks! had to run it for php7.1 but works. thanks!